# What is the advantage of using union for struct and array of same size

Tags: c++

I read somewhere a piece of code for defining 3d coordinate. So, they used `x`, `y` & `z` coordinate like this below:

```
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            float x, y, z;
        };
        float _v[3];
    };
```

My question is that why a `union` is required here and also what is the advantage of using struct with an array?

Comment: None unless you want Undefined Behaviour or want to research and check compiler extensions.  _"...undefined behavior to read from the member of the union that wasn't most recently written."_ see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union

Comment: The union makes the struct and the array occupy the same space. It's a hack at an attempt to allow `x` to be a synonym for `_v[0]`. It assumes no padding in the struct and will break spectacularly on a system that adds them.

Comment: It would be a very odd compiler that would pad the struct and the array differently. While it is undefined behavior in terms of the C++ language standard, it is generally well understood behavior in terms of the code the compiler will generate. While language purists hate it, people who write embedded code often depend on this kind of thing.

Comment: @RobK Language purists hate him! The top 10 things the embedded engineer does that will guarantee undefined behaviour! You won't believe #3!

Comment: @RobK it's not just padding, the UB can also come the compiler optimising out the read from the non-written member because it can prove it has not been updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Important note:** this construct leads to undefined behavior. What follows is a description of its authors' intentions, which, unfortunately, many compilers translate to precisely the behavior the authors expect, which in turn leads to proliferation of code like that.

`union` construct is not really required here: the authors used it for convenience. The reason they put a `union` there is to give themselves a syntax for accessing `x`, `y`, and `z` in two distinct ways:

- **By specifying the field name** - that is, `coord.x`, `coord.y`, or `coord.z`, or
- **By specifying the field index** - that is, `coord._v[0]`, `coord._v[1]`, or `coord._v[2]`.

An approach that provides comparable functionality without running into undefined behavior is to use inline member functions for your access:

```
struct Vector3D {
    int v[3];
    int& x() { return v[0]; }
    int& y() { return v[1]; }
    int& z() { return v[2]; }
};

int main() {
    Vector3D coord;
    coord.v[0] = 5;
    cout << coord.x() << endl;
    coord.y() = 10;
    cout << coord.v[1] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/M7TMrI)

Comment: Is this also undefined behaviour in C? or just C++?

Comment: @9a3eedi [only in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11373203/335858)

Answer (score 4):

As Gill Bates says, in this way you can (maybe) access the 3 coordinates both as `x, y, z` and as `v[0], v[1], v[2]`
But as per @Richard Critten comment, this is actually an UB.

You can get the same result in a "safe" way with something like this:

```
struct Coordinates
{
    Coordinates():x(v[0]), y(v[1]), z(v[2])
    {
    }

    int v[3];
    int& x;
    int& y;
    int& z;
};
```

i.e., using references to the array values and initializing them in constructor

Size of this struct will be obviously different (larger) than the union you show in OP

Comment: "Size of this struct will be obviously different (larger)" That's quite an understatement: the size will be *significantly* larger. In fact, you'll spend at least twice as much memory before the effects of padding for memory alignment is considered, which is pretty expensive. On ideone the size grows from 12 bytes to 40 bytes ([demo](http://ideone.com/oAOwAC)).

Answer (score 2):

This way you can address the 3d coordinate as a struct..

```
foo.x;
foo.y; // etc
```

But it also allows you to get the 3 variables as an array while occupying the same space (that's the plan at least), accessing them like..

```
foo._v[0] // x, etc
```

Anyway, that's the idea. But the moment the struct has any sort of padding between members your array will be misaligned and you will end up reading garbage values. Long story short, this code has undefined behaviour, a bad implementation that shouldn't be used.